# $.Document.Ready twice on same page , Which will execute first?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guy's i am bit confused about the following code, in bellow code has two function  then which will execute first Function1() or Function2 () ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // some code here for function1()
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  // other code here for function2()
});
```

Comment: why do you need two?

Comment: The top one will execute first. Why 2 document ready's on one page?

Comment: I sometimes use 2 `$(document).ready` if I have an aspx page and ascx user control, so there can be some excuse ;) In a rendered document it will make 2 `$(document).ready` (or more, if more .ascx files are added and need to handle it)

Comment: This kind of scenario happens when there are two partial views - having `$(document).ready()` each - being called from one page, or master page...

Comment: First is 1st, Second is 2nd.. That's It...!

Comment: @suresh.g What is secone?

Comment: @Doink yes as Kamil T said i have an aspx page and ascx user control,

Comment: @NULL that is spell mistake

Comment: but in my case it's executing randomly sometimes function1() executes first sometimes function2()

Comment: It was harder to try it than to ask, wasn't it?

Comment: @user2553512 show a proof of random behaviour, most likely it has something to do with the specific code inside the function. If the function contains console.log() only it will always log the first message first.

Comment: To help explain why 2 document ready, you might have some component based framework or portlet based application where each component or portlet can have it's own triggers. If you put all together, you end up with such a scenario, so the question is really interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will be executed. You are registering events to trigger when document is ready. You can register more than one event for a given object, even if it's triggered by the same action.

Normally, I would expect the code that is declared first to trigger first, but I wouldn't write code that has dependencies in different blocks as it will be failure prone.

I would assume such a scenario in component based frameworks (like Wicket), where each component can have it's ready block, but if they are independant from each other, you wouldn't have to care about which one executes first.

If you have code where the execution order is an issue, I would recommend searching for some other approach to avoid this. As other answers have already stated, you can expect one order, but I wouldn't trust in all browser implementations, and worse than that, in future implementations.

So, as a general rule: keep things simple, if you need more than one event for one object it's fine as long as they're not dependant, else put them in the same block.

Answer (score 3):

Function 1 will execute first. jQuery will always execute event handlers in the order they were bound (bearing in mind that delegated handlers will be executed after direct handlers because they only happen as the event bubbles up through the DOM - but that doesn't apply here).

This is documented in a parenthetical in the [`on` method docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> (Event handlers bound to an element are called in the same order that they were bound.)

Comment: This is true even for `addEventListener`

Comment: @PaulS. - No it's not. At least, it's not guaranteed in all browsers because the spec basically says that order of multiple handlers is undefined.

Comment: but in my case it's executing randomly sometimes function1() executes first sometimes function2()

Comment: @PaulS.: More accurately, it [was explicitly not specified in DOM2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-basic-h3), but then [the order was specified in DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#glossary-candidate-event-handlers) ([also flagged up here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#changes-DOMEvents2to3Changes-flow)).

Comment: It might have been nice to mention the random behaviour in your question. You're not doing something asynchronous in one or both functions are you? E.g., an Ajax call?

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder - you're doing all the heavy lifting on this answer. I hadn't seen that point in the DOM3 spec, and indeed although I knew I had seen the relevant bit in the DOM2 spec I couldn't find it again with Google. Apologies to PaulS.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Happy to pitch in. :-)

Answer (score 0):

First document.ready will execute first.

Answer (score 0):

First function 1 will execute first, as jQuery always executes handlers as they were written

**Plus**

*You can have as many of them as you wish, and they will be executed in the order that the `$()` or `$(document).ready()` functions are executed. (i.e. each handler is added to the queue)*

Comment: @NULL The `$(document).ready` function adds to what is essentially an _event queue_ - the functions in these declarations will all be executed, either at the document.ready event, or immediately if that event has already fired, in order of declaration.